# Google Play In-App Billing Security

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, google-play

Here is part of **Security and Design** section of In-App Billing on Google's site:

> Perform signature verification tasks on a server
>
> If practical, you should perform signature verification on a remote server and not on a device. Implementing the verification process on a server ***makes it difficult*** for attackers to break the verification process by reverse engineering your .apk file. If you do offload security processing to a remote server, be sure that the device-server handshake is secure.

so here, does "makes it difficult" mean that no matter what, it will always be possible to hack in-app purchases?

Comment: We say world is full of gem, so the Internet is also full of gem. You can't have 100% security, but doing things on the server is more "secure" because the key is not stored on client (mobile), instead it's on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your developed app, which you can upload to play store, is more secure from cracking it if you use a signature verficiation on a remote server. Almost every app can be decompiled, but if you store your verification process on a remote server, a cracker must get this too. He can not see it directly in the reverse enginneered source.
There are many possibilities to make your .apk more secure from cracking it.

Comment: The idea was about in-app purchases. Let's suppose I run an MMORPG game and I want to secure in-app billing. Will performing signature verification on server make it only more difficult, or impossible to break by hackers?

Comment: Unfortunately only more difficult.